# shell script looping

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to bash scripting and trying to write a loop to run a curl command but however getting errors. Please suggest the write syntax.

```sh
    #!/usr/bin/env sh
    start = $1
    end = $2
    
    start=$(date -d $start +%Y-%m-%d)
    end=$(date -d $end +%Y-%m-%d)
    
    while [[ $start -le $end ]]
    do
        echo $start
        curl -H "command, which can't be shared"
        start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
    done
```

The command line to run the script used `sh filename.sh "2022-02-01" "2022-02-25".`

However, the first error I received is windows cannot find '2022-02-01'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

Please suggest the errors.

Comment: Problem is *`spaces`*  arround `=` equal sign.

Comment: Also, `[[ -le ]]` compares integers, not dates; it'd be better to convert the dates to seconds-since-epoch format to convert them. And `[[ ]]` is a bash extension (technically a ksh extension that bash copied); if you want to use it in a script, use a bash shebang (i.e.. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`) instead of plain sh.